# Connecting "source code on the side" with a debugging session

Tags: c++, debugging, unix

I have *most* of the source code of the application I'm debugging, apart from certain external open source libraries that were compiled in optimized mode. The application crashes inside one of the external libraries, for which the debugger shows only disassembly code.

In order to figure out what's going on I printed input variables, but that didn't give me enough clue, so now I want to step into the external library code.

I downloaded source code of the external library, but it's currently is sitting separately from the rest of the source code, with the call into the offending function still being passed into the optimized lib*.so. I'd prefer not to change the build to avoid possible inconsistencies with how other developer run it.

Thus the question: is it possible to connect the downloaded source code of the external library for the duration of the debugging session, without altering the build?

The source is in C++, OS is a flavor of Unix, I'm debugging from Eclipse via gdb.

Comment: Does `objdump -WL libwhatever.so` indicate that the library has a line table? Were the libraries obtained from your OS vendor?

Comment: Suggestion: Build the debug version of the external lib so you can debug against it to see if you have the same results. Yes, it's not canonical.  Yes you don't want to ship that way. But if it helps find and fix the bug, you win. Then you put the debug lib off to the side and go back to linking against the official lib.